# Triangles : isoceles and angles inside with other triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have this, what seems basic triangle problem, and not certain if the given information is sufficient to solve the problem of finding an angle.
We have one main isoceles and another one inside of it.
I have attached here a diagram, and we wish to find the angle in red:

[image]

The labels blue means : lengths PQ = QR
The label green means : lengths QS = QT
The given angle PQS = 24 (deg)

We wish to find angle in red , angle RST.

I am trying to figure this out only using geometric principle without trying to use a system of algebraic equations. I tried to create parallel lines to help, but it did not, I tried to make use of principle of exterior angle theorem, but still could not get it.
Hope someone here can help me on this.

Comment: You are correct, i will fix the diagram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the solution of @Donald Splutterwit might seem like algebra and equations, it is really straight-forward geometry, using the principle that the three angles of a triangle sum to $180^o$.

Perhaps the following may be another helpful way to exhibit the geometry of the situation.
[image: isosceles within isosceles]
Since $PRQ$ and $STQ$ are isosceles and share vertex $Q$, let the circle with center $Q$ and radius $QT$ intersect $PQ$ at $U$ and $PR$ at $V$, and join $TU$. Thus, since$$\frac{QU}{QP}=\frac{QT}{QR}$$then$$TU\parallel RP$$and arcs$$\ VT= SU$$so that$$\angle VST=\angle STU$$But$$\angle SQU=2\angle STU$$Therefore$$\angle SQU=2\angle VST$$that is$$\angle SQP=2\angle RST$$Thus under the given conditions, the angle we are looking for is always half the given angle.

Comment: Hi Edward, this looks very beautiful, your approach, using more proportion number kind of based way. Thank you so much for this approach.

Comment: I was actually thinking this could be related to Circle and angles sub-tended by a common arc type of theorem.

Comment: Hi Edward, i am having trouble with some of the line items. SO I think I get the Ratio you setup, it comes from similar triangles I believe. But I can't figure out why lengths TU // RP. What geometry theorem or corollary helps with showing that TU // RP. I have a feeling this may be very easy, but I am not able to see it.

Comment: Palu, in Elements VI, 2, Euclid proves that a line which divides the sides of a triangle proportionally is parallel to the base. This proves TU//RP.

Comment: OK, so since one is able to get that Ratio equation, using letters T and U, that would mean that T and U would be parallel to RP. I was not aware of this fact by Euclid, thanks for telling me this. But if we slide point "T" to the left or right, then TU will not be parallel. Visually you can see that would be the case, but can one still create the proportion equation you setup. I think i must be missing some small geometry idea here.

Comment: I think i got it, my issue with the ratio. QU = QT because they form the radius of that inner circle. Also QP = QR because they are the radius of the outer circle.

Comment: I made an edit to clarify the construction. The larger circle looks nice but isn't really necessary.  Since QT=QS=QU, and QR=QP, then TU will always be parallel to RP. If you slide T to the left, triangle STQ is no longer isosceles.

Comment: Hi Edward, one last thing is the arcs VT=SU. I believe that they are the same, visually i sense they are the same, but I am having trouble trying to see a way to prove these arcs lengths are the same using geometry principles. Once I can see this the geometry proving this, that is all i need to fully follow all the steps. If you can show me this, i will award you this question.

Comment: Fair enough.  I think the best way is to join UV.  Then angle VST= angle STU because they are alternate interior of parallel lines, and angle VST = angle VUT because they stand on the same arc VT. So angle STU=angle VUT.  Therefore arc SU = arc VT (Euclid VI, 26).

Comment: Hi Edward, I see that you have invoked another of Euclids theorems. I have searched and found that there is a geometry theorem that states that 2 parallel lines crossing a circle will create 2 equal arcs.

Comment: I would need to go look up your reference to Euclid: (Euclid VI, 26).  I will award you this question, because you are helping out as much as you can.

Comment: It says that equal angles in equal circles stand on equal arcs. The same is of course true for equal angles in one and the same circle. The proof is short. Have a look.

Comment: Hi, I looked it up, i am not sure if you got the right book number or the proposition, from this link I found a different thing: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookVI/propVI26.html

Comment: Sorry, it's III, 26.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\widehat{QRP}= \widehat{RPQ}=x$, so $\widehat{RQP}=180-2x$, so $\widehat{RQS}=156-2x$, so the sum of the angles $\widehat{QST}$ and $ \widehat{QTS}$ is $24+2x$, so they are both $x+12$, so $\widehat{RTS}=168-x$, so $\widehat{RST}=12$.

Comment: Hi Donald, that is a great solution done in an algebraic way. Just wondering if there maybe some principle, since there seems to be so much symmetry that one can deduce that angle RST is say half of angle PQS.

Comment: If you replace $24$ with $2y$, the same argument will lead to the conclusion $\widehat{RST}=y$.